# Sitecore 8, Index tries to find item in Danish language

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I have all the items in English version only. But in the crawling log I am seeing these kinds of warnings for all the items. (Crawling.log is now above 350 MBs because of these warnings ).

```
15040 12:41:36 WARN  [Index=sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master] Full Rebuild Started
    WARN  SitecoreItemCrawler : AddItem : Could not build document data sitecore://core/{EB2E4FFD-2761-4653-B052-26A64D385227}?lang=da&ver=1 - Latest version could not be found. Skipping.
```

I don't know why its trying to find items in Danish language. How can I resolve this Issue?

Comment: Is this specific to 'sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master' or all index crawls?

Comment: Its with all the crawl indexes.

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because Sitecore by default comes with 3 languages (in addition to EN): Japanese, German and Danish. Despite the fact that you don't have any language versions in those languages, Sitecore checks if it can crawl them. You can remove them by:

- Install the three languages via Control Panel -> Globalization -> Add a new language
- Delete the newly created languages via Control Panel -> Globalization -> Delete a language
- Rebulid the indexes via Control Panel -> Indexing -> Indexing Manager

Source: http://blog.tibenet.no/post/remove-default-languages-from-sitecore-7